# Manipulating PDF Files and using Adobe Form Fields

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, pdf, pdf-generation

I have searched through stack-overflow in response to a similar question.

I currently have a pre-made PDF, which I have gone and used Adobe Acrobat PRO to create some entry fields within the PDF.

Once I have completed the entire form, I would like to use PHP to run through the PDF fill in the form with the associated information from a database, and re-save the PDF.

Currently I am using an X,Y value system and using ZEND_PDF to make that happen, which works great, but effeciency is down the tubes when i'm trying to create a complex PDF. And I think creating the form within the PDF first would be a much more effecient way of doing it.

I have read about using FDF as a possible solution, but not sure if this is a the best route.
After I created the fields in Acrobat, I save it, and go to  FORMS -> EXPORT FORM DATA AS -> FDF or XML

But my response in the file is as follows if i open it in notepad:

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</F(this-is-my-pdf-pro.pdf)/Fields[<</T(contractType)/V/Off>>]/ID[<545A7F611C15BEFE4DFE4C7C829256AE><60AD70B6B530BF42B5F2D52956886AA7>]/UF(this-is-my-pdf-pro.pdf)>>/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

And I don't seem to see any reference to fields at all other than the 1 RADIO selection option... I have text-fields in there as well but not being displayed.
So my question comes down to, what is the best solution for this?

1. Continue using X,Y coordinates to fill in my PDF
2. using Adobe Acrobat to create the fields and run a search and replace or something?

If anyone has any solutions I would be much appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use WKHTMLTOPDF as a route to manage some of my fields and information.

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [PDFlib](http://pdflib.com) successfully to fill in "template" PDFs. It has a "blocks" system, where you can 'draw' blocks on a PDF, and programmatically fill them in at run-time by simply specifying "fill Block X with content Y" - there's image, text, and PDF block types. Images can be of pretty much any type, the text can contain arbitrary pseudo-html and PDF-specific type formatting strings. The PDF block just allows you to embed another PDF within the block.

The drawback is that PDFlib is pretty pricey to license.

Answer (score 0):

[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) should help you extract the fields from an existing PDF document and 
then fill the PDF with actual values.  But it is strange that Acrobat doesn't extract the fields correctly, so you may have done something wrong when creating the fields (I don't know Acrobat so can't help in this).

Anyway, you may check which fields PDFtk finds like this:

```
pdftk form.pdf dump_data_fields
```

and then fill in the form like this:

```
pdftk form.pdf fill_form field-values.fdf output form-out.pdf
```

PHP has tools to create [FDF files](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.fdf.php).

Comment: Thanks for your response to my question, I forgot that I hadn't marked this  complete. I was able to use WKHTMLTOPDF as a solution for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the question is that old... :-)